# Eigenstates harmonic oscillator with mass matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

Consider the 2D harmonic oscillator

$H = \langle \nabla, M\nabla  \rangle+ \vert x \vert^2$ where $x \in \mathbb R^2$ and $M$ is a symmetric mass matrix with strictly positive eigenvalues.

Is it known if in this case the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian are still explicit?

PS: I think I can see that the ground state is $e^{-\langle x, M^{-1/2} x \rangle}$ but I do not see any systematic approach to analyze excited states.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you actually meant the Hamiltonian is $H=\mathbf{p}^T M \mathbf{p}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{p}=-i\nabla$. I write both $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ as column vectors. Diagonalize $M$: $ M=O^T D O $, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive eigenvalues, $O$ is an orthogonal matrix (so $OO^T=1$). Now define new variables

$$ \tilde{\mathbf{p}}=O\mathbf{p}, \tilde{\mathbf{x}}=O\mathbf{x} $$

The new variables still satisfy canonical commutation relations. Then the Hamiltonian becomes $H=\tilde{\mathbf{p}}^TD\tilde{\mathbf{p}}+\tilde{\mathbf{x}}^T\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$, which is just a bunch of decoupled harmonic oscillators. The energy eigenvalues and eigenfunctions can be obtained from here.